# How to find any occuerences where the value jumps up by higher than 5%, or lower then -5% in consecutive sequences nos

Tags: sql-server

I have to find the value jumps up higher than 5% and lower than -5% in consecutive sequences.

```
declare @unit table(sequencenumber int,value money)
insert into @unit
values(1,10.0),(2,10.2),(3,9.8),(4,9.7),(5,9.54),(6,9.1),(7,9.3),(8,9.9),(9,10.2),(10,10.1).
```

I have tried like below

```
select (l.value/r.value)/r.value as change
from @unit l
join @unit r
on l.sequencenumber=(r.sequencenumber+1)
where (l.value/r.value)/r.value>0.05
```

is this valid query result or do we need to modify something different?

Comment: Show expected result please